# Find Contacts Custom Searches Zip Code Range Search lists duplicates

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts, custom-search

I entered a range of zip codes and the selected records were duplicated. How do I go about reporting the issue to have my request analyzed for an error on my part or get bug fixed?

Comment: Hi Bill - welcome - first off i suggest you flesh out the above, eg 'i entered' do you mean, in a search, imported, something else? 'selected records were duplicated' do you mean Contact records or something else. imagine describing to an alien how to make a cup of tea (or similar everyday task which actually has a lot of steps involved when you try to break it down). Then ideally you or someone else can try the same steps to see if they can replicate the behaviour on a test site, eg http://drupal.demo.civicrm.org/, then if it is replicable, your or someone can file a bug issue if it is a bug

Comment: or try and persuade someone via stealth or wealth to have them add a new feature if that is what is required. hth

Comment: @petednz-fuzion - Thanks for the reply and welcome. I tried the demo link and is was not found. I’ll see if I can find another. I didn’t think I was needing an enhancement. I was just getting what I thought were erroneous results from a report from a menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question suggests you're using the Zip Code Range custom search - but this is a *very* old way to handle zip code range searches, from before Advanced Search could do them (10-12 years ago).  In my opinion, this search should have been removed a long time ago, but that's an issue if someone has a smart group built on it.

The more-modern (though not most modern!) way to do a zip code range search is **Search menu » Advanced Search**.  Check the **Range** box (see screenshot) in the *Address Fields* above *Postal Code*.

The *most* modern approach is to use Search Kit, but despite being more powerful than Advanced Search, it's also got a steeper learning curve, so I recommend Advanced Search for now.

[image]

Comment: As a new user, I have no idea what is old or new in the system. Thank you of your answer. Th advanced search worked fine.